# Yii2- How to add a search box in grid view

Tags: search, gridview, yii2

I am new to Yii-2.
I have a grid-view in my index page which some entries are displaying.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        //'meter_id',

        [
            'label' => 'Meter MSN',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                return $d->meter->meter_msn;
            },
           // 'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'meter_id', \app\models\Meters::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "All Meters", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
        'imsi',
        'telecom',
        'status',
        [
            'label' => 'Created By',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                if (is_object($data))
                    return $data->created->name;
                return ' - ';
            },
            //'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'created_by', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Created By", 'class' => 'form-control']),
        ],
        'comments',
        'historic',


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Now I want to add a search-box against `Meter MSN`. In above code the filter is hidden so it was working but I don't want to add a drop-down instead I want a search box.

Below is my search class

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = MetersInventoryStore::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'meter_id' => $this->meter_id,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'store_id' => $this->store_id,
        'meter_serial'=>$this->meter_serial,
        //            'historic' => $this->historic,
        'status'=>'SIM Installed',

    ])
      //  ->orFilterWhere(['status'=>'Communication Failed'])
    ;

    //       $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'meter_serial', $this->meter_serial])
    //        ->andFilterWhere(['like','meter_id',$this->meter_id]);
    $query->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

How can I place a search-box in it? As the simple search class will set up the search functionality by default. But my `MSN` value is coming from a function so I have no idea how can I place a search-box. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you create CRUD with Gii you can use _search.php form to create a search form and develop your search class. But i don't know if this is your case. Meter msn in a value in a table? if yes you can make a simple search in a db column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for add  filter field in a calculated column you should add  a pubblic var in 
in your search model

```
public function search($params)
{
    public $your_column;

   // declare as safe 
   public function rules()
   {
    return [
       ...
        [[  'your_column', ], 'safe'],

    ];
   }

   $query = MetersInventoryStore::find();
```

and then refer to your_column in grid_view

```
 ...
 'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    //'meter_id',

    [
        'attribute' => 'your_column',
        'label' => 'Meter MSN',
        'value' => function ($d) {
            return $d->meter->meter_msn;
        },
    ],
```

And last your searchModel you  must expand your filter condition for manage properly your calculated column based  on the filter value you passed.

You can find some sample in this tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/